# Delete message sent from SMSManager

Tags: android

I am stuck on a security issue. I am trying to send message from my android app using SMS Manager and after sending message it saves message in my Phone's inbox. But i want messages to not to be save or delete programmatically.

Here is the code which I am using:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Main6Activity.this,
                        Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

  if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Main6Activity.this,
                            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
                    } 
       else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Main6Activity.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
            }
   }
   else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Main6Activity.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String permissions[], 
             int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phone, null, "your password is 
                      "+password, null, null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent \nMake 
                        sure you have enough balance to send message",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "SMS faild, please try again.", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: sound something fishy!

Answer (score 1):

> But i want messages to not to be save or delete programatically.

This is not possible on Android 4.4+. Only the user's chosen SMS client app can modify the contents of the `Sms` provider.