# Conversation appearing in default messaging application

Tags: java, android, sms, toast, smsmanager

I have successfully sent an sms programmatically using these lines below.

```
SmsManager smgr = SmsManager.getDefault();
smgr.sendTextMessage(phoneNum, null, bodyText, null, null);
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SMS Sent Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

But after executing the above code, a conversation has appeared in default messaging app.

**How can send sms without appearing a conversation of it in default sms application ?**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is not possible on newer Android versions(4.4+)

Original Answer:-
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46141415/8097716